# Weak acid titration curve

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, titration

At the beginning of a weak acid titration curve (when titrated with a strong base), there is a sharp increase of pH before it levels out more due to the buffer solution that will occur. But why is that sharp increase there at the beginning? Is it because since the weak acid is weak, it is easier to increase it's pH when adding a strong base?

Comment: Why not to calculate pH as function of molar ratio base versus acid ? You will see then why.

Comment: Imagine adding your strong base to just water.

Comment: ... but also listen to what Poutnik says and do the math!

Comment: @Karl - Thanks for the link, yes, it does answer my question. I will also try to do the math to get a deeper understanding myself.